# Scoping problems when using geeglm inside a function

Tags: r

I want to use a function for bootstrapping my clustered data. I want to use my gee model on each bootstrap replicate. When I use my function I get an error saying that the object "id" is not found. I think it may have something to do with the use of a global and local environment.

My data has the following structure:

```
Outcome Time Treatment  Cluster ID
500     1    1          Carl    1
800     2    1          Carl    1
1000    3    1          Carl    1
1200    1    2          Pete    2
400     2    2          Pete    2
550     3    2          Pete    2
300     1    1          Rose    3
```

My syntax is the following:

```
 clusbootreg <- function(formula,family,data,id, waves,corstr,cluster, reps=4){
  reg1 <- geeglm(formula,family,data,id,waves,corstr)
  clusters <- names(table(cluster))
  sterrs <- matrix(NA, nrow=reps, ncol=length(coef(reg1)))
  for(i in 1:reps){
    index <- sample(1:length(clusters), length(clusters), replace=TRUE)
    aa <- clusters[index]
    bb <- table(aa)
    bootdat <- NULL
    for(j in 1:max(bb)){
      cc <- data[cluster %in% names(bb[bb %in% j]),]
      for(k in 1:j){
        bootdat <- rbind(bootdat, cc)
      }
    }
    sterrs[i,] <- coef(geeglm(formula,family,bootdat,id,waves,corstr))
  }
  val <- cbind(coef(reg1),apply(sterrs,2,sd))
  colnames(val) <- c("Estimate","Std. Error")
  return(val)
}

clusbootreg(formula=Outcome~Treatment+Time+Time*Treatment,family=Gamma(link = "log"),data=data,id=ID,waves=Time, cluster=data$Cluster, reps=4)
```

The following error message appears:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'id' not found
```

Is there anyone who knows how to solve this? I am stuck for two days now.

Traceback tells me the following

```
11: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
10: eval(extras, data, env)
9: model.frame.default(formula = formula, data = data, subset = waves, 
       weights = id, na.action = corstr, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
8: stats::model.frame(formula = formula, data = data, subset = waves, 
       weights = id, na.action = corstr, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
7: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
6: eval(mf, parent.frame())
5: glm(formula = formula, family = family, data = data, weights = id, 
       subset = waves, na.action = corstr)
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval(glmcall, parent.frame())
2: geeglm(formula, family, data, id, waves, corstr) at #2
```

Comment: I think you should pass `id = data$ID`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment; I already tried that but it did not work..

Comment: Well, what does `traceback()` tell you? You need to find out where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: Of course; I added the debug output; I think the error occurs in the model

Comment: I just noticed that maybe R uses glm instead of geeglm. That is strange as the geeglm function works when I just run one model..

Comment: `geeglm` calls `glm` internally.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the difference between positional argument matching and named arguments. After I correct all the mistakes, the error still persisted.

The problem is that you create the formula outside of the function body, which results in it being associated with the global environment. You need to fix that:

```
testDF <- read.table(text = "Outcome Time Treatment  Cluster ID
                     500     1    1          Carl    1
                     800     2    1          Carl    1
                     1000    3    1          Carl    1
                     1200    1    2          Pete    2
                     400     2    2          Pete    2
                     550     3    2          Pete    2
                     300     1    1          Rose    3", header = TRUE)

library(geepack)

clusbootreg <- function(formula,family,data,id, waves,corstr,cluster, reps=4){

  environment(formula) <- environment() #associate the correct environment with the formula
  geeglm(formula,family,data,id = id, waves = waves, corstr = corstr)

}

clusbootreg(formula=Outcome~Treatment+Time+Time*Treatment,
            family=Gamma(link = "log"),
            data=testDF,id=testDF$ID,waves=testDF$Time, 
            cluster=data$Cluster, reps=4, corstr = "independence")
#works
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! I have to look more into it why but it works perfectly.